# Difficulty showing graph information between two dates by 15 minute interval in grafana

Tags: mongodb, graph, grafana

I get the information from mongodb using the simple json plugin graphana and display it using graph but apparently there is a problem with drawing the line graph as you see below:

[image: grafana]

**query mongo:**

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "$add": [
                { "$subtract": [
                    { "$subtract": [ "$date", new Date('1970-01-01') ] },
                    { "$mod": [ 
                        { "$subtract": [ "$date", new Date('1970-01-01') ] },
                        1000 * 60 * 15
                    ]}
                ] }
            ]
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

**Result Query :**

[image: result query mongodb]

Please advise
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

It seemed so funny I just had to add this code to sort the information:

```
    db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "$add": [
                { "$subtract": [
                    { "$subtract": [ "$date", new Date('1970-01-01') ] },
                    { "$mod": [ 
                        { "$subtract": [ "$date", new Date('1970-01-01') ] },
                        1000 * 60 * 15
                    ]}
                ] }
            ]
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 },
        {"$sort":{"_id":-1}}
    }}
])
```

**Result:**

[image: result]